# How to have <s:if> with two conditions in Struts 2

Tags: jsp, struts2, ognl

I iterate through a list of items, and need to show a specific dropdown list if the state of element is equal to student or teacher. The following code shows all fields but does not show the dropdown for any of the elements!

```
 <s:iterator value="listOfPeople" status="element">
   .....
  <s:if test='%{elements[#element.index].Status.equalsIgnoreCase("Student") ||
          elements[#element.index].Status.equalsIgnoreCase("Teacher")}'>

            <s:select name="elements[%{#element.index}].Status"
                               id="elements[%{#element.index}].Status"
                               label="Status"
                               list="#{'Student':'Student','Teacher':'Teacher'}"
                               headerKey = "-1"
                               headerValue=" "
                               value="%{Status}"
             />

    </s:if>
```

**In Controller:**

```
    PeopleModel peopleModel = new PeopleModel();
    listOfPeople = peopleModel.findPeople();
    System.out.println("size is:" + listOfPeople.size());  //returns 8
    return "listPeople";
```

**My Model:**

```
    List<People> people = new ArrayList();
    final Session session = HibernateUtil.getSession();
    try {
        final Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
        try {

            Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(People.class, "People")
            people.addAll((List<People>) criteria.list());
            if (!tx.wasCommitted()) {
                tx.commit();
            }
            if (session.isOpen()) {
                session.close();
            }
            System.out.println("size is ::: " + people.size());   //returns 8
            return people;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            tx.rollback();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } finally {
        HibernateUtil.closeSession();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Result of the following code

```
   Status: ${Status}
   <br/>value : [<s:property value="elements[%{#element.index}].Status" />]
```

is

```
Status : Principle
value : [] Status : Student
value : [] Status : Teacher
value : [] Status : Teacher
value : [] Status : Teacher
value : [] Status : Teacher
value : [] Status : Teacher
value : [] Status : Teacher
value : []
```

The above result is showing the first person's status separate to the other ones thats why the last value : [] is not showing any status.

If I take out Status: ${Status} the result would be

```
value : []
value : []
value : []
value : []
value : []
value : []
value : []
value : []
```

Comment: You are iterating `listOfPeople` but in `<s:if>` tag you get values from `elements` collection. Why?

Comment: @AleksandrM because it is a listofArray that need to iterate through all its elements. [0],[1] etc

Comment: Still doesn't make sense. Maybe you can show your action class and entities you are trying to iterate.

Comment: And why did you edit the question with the code in my answer ? Future visitors won't get it. You are also using (now) `Status` with the capital `S`, and **it won't work**.

Comment: @AndreaLigios becuase the second code did not work as well, s was a typo it should be capital

Comment: You are obviously doing something wrong. Post your entities you are trying iterate.

Comment: @AlexCartio1: So your `listOfPeople` list holds `People`? Post the `People` class.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Put `%{}` around the whole expression, not in the middle as in other attributes of other tags:

Also use a more appropriate equality function for Strings, [like described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14023299/1654265)

```
<s:if test='%{elements[#element.index].status.equalsIgnoreCase("Student") ||
              elements[#element.index].status.equalsIgnoreCase("Teacher")}'>
```

**EDIT**: dude, you are doing a lot of odd things;

1. `${Status}` is JSP EL, you have no need of using it;
2. You are iterating a source, and checking another source: printing `<s:property value="elements[%{#element.index}].Status" />` gives you an empty result, and I can't see that `elements` thing anywhere in your code;
3. the capital letter as first in an attribute is WRONG, because if the variable is named `foo` and the getter is `getFoo()`, in page you will have `.foo`, not `.Foo`. If your variable is named `Foo`, it is against the specs / best practices, let's start variables names with a lowercase letter.

Then If you have `private Object Status`, change it to `private Object status;`, along with the getter and the setter, and in page use:

```
<s:iterator value="listOfPeople" status="element">
    <s:if test='%{listOfPeople[#element.index].status.equalsIgnoreCase("Student") ||
                  listOfPeople[#element.index].status.equalsIgnoreCase("Teacher")}'>
```

or with a var

```
<s:iterator value="listOfPeople" status="element" var="row">
    <s:if test='%{row.status.equalsIgnoreCase("Student") ||
                  row.status.equalsIgnoreCase("Teacher")}'>
```

or simply

```
<s:iterator value="listOfPeople" status="element">
    <s:if test='%{status.equalsIgnoreCase("Student") ||
                  status.equalsIgnoreCase("Teacher")}'>
```

Strange code leads to weird results... then use it straight :)

Comment: it does not work, I removed the if to make sure the <s:select is working which is but when I put the condition it does not show anything. I even removed the "or" to make it simpler to no avail

Comment: print `<br/>value : [<s:property value="elements[%{#element.index}].status" />]` before the s:if in your loop, and post the results.

Comment: all right question is updated, please note I have 8 elements but the code you provided is unable to show the status of the last one.

Comment: because last one is empty... ?

Comment: Because `elements` has less elements than `listOfPeople`... ?

Comment: @AleksandrM what do you mean by that ? isn't it just iterating through listOfPeople?

Comment: @AndreaLigios it is not, thats why it is weird, any way the reason that the if condition does not work is mysterious !

Comment: @AlexCartio1: Yes and no. Why do you refuse to show your model?

Comment: @AleksandrM because I reckon it is sending the correct info to the browser, anyway Ive included my controller and model codes.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to have those conditions and `if` tag at all if you need to have the `select` tag being preselected on the `Status` you should provide valid keys. The `headerKey = "-1"` is invalid because it's not a `String`. Try `headerKey = " "`, the keys should not be empty. if the preselected value doesn't match the key the `headerValue` will be shown. For example

```
<s:iterator value="listOfPeople" status="element">    
  <s:select name="elements[%{#element.index}].Status"
           id="elements[%{#element.index}].Status"
           label="Status"
           list="#{'Student':'Student','Teacher':'Teacher'}"
           headerKey=" "
           headerValue=" "
           value="%{Status}"/>    
</s:iterator>
```

Comment: Thanks but as shown in the question, some items may have other types of status such as 'principle', in this way, an item with 'principle' status will be shown as having a blank status which is misleading for users. In addition, I want to unable users from changing the status of an item with any type of status other than student and teacher statuses; that's why I put the if condition to avoid showing select for those items in the first place.

Comment: Another issue is that when I copied your code it shown an error which says Encountered ":" at line 1, column 13. Was expecting one of : "}" ... "." ... etc , I need to change it to {'Teacher','Student'} whats the reason?

Comment: I don't know what is an error  but how about an option to use an input textfield to keep the current status? With the select tag as is and as you see from this answer can't handle statuses other from the listed.

Comment: I could solve it using a combination of yours and Andrea's answer. thanks