# org.apache.jasper.JasperException: quote symbol expected

Tags: jsp

Show.jsp

```xml
<s:if test="%{assistanceDetailsObj != null && (assistanceDetailsObj.applnStatus == '05' || assistanceDetailsObj.applnStatus == '06')}">
```

I'm getting Following error :

> org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /Show.jsp(116,24) quote symbol expected

Any suggestions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to have a if with two conditions in Struts2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22316082/how-to-have-a-if-with-two-conditions-in-struts2)

Comment: Are you sure that `Show.jsp(116,24)` points to this `<s:if>` tag?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like some quote problem in your Show.jsp, you should look exactly for line 116 and search for something like this:

```
<s:property value=1 />
```

or

```
<s:iterator var=item value="itemList">
```

JSTL attributes inside tags need the quote.

See the examples above solved:

```
<s:property value="1" />
```

or

```
<s:iterator var="item" value="itemList">
```